# Help to ID this little SOT-89 transistor/diode

Tags: transistors, identification, components, surface-mount

I've been looking for the proper resources in order to find out what component this is.

The manufacturer wouldn't provide any schematics or technical information.

The inscriptions on it are :  KE with an X printed sideways.

[image]

Unfortunately, this device (whatever it is) is shorted on one side.

Comment: Where did the chip come from?  It could be helpful if you add a photo of the circuit it was removed from.

Comment: I don't see an "X".

Comment: *"Thanks for accepting me as a newcomer"*.  I don't see how you can possibly know whether you *have* been accepted at the time of writing the question.  We don't actually accept or reject users, but we do up or down vote posts.  Only time will tell how your question was received according to the votes.

Comment: *"The manufacturer wouldn't provide ANY scematics nor technical info's."*  **What** manufacturer?  Manufacturer of **what**?  If you know the manufacturer of this part, then you should tell us.

Comment: *"with an X printed sideways"*.  I don't see any "X" either.  Also a "X" printed sideways (rotated 90 deg?) would still look like a X, so how could you tell if it was "sideways"?

Comment: Okay, It comes from a Marshall Dual screen SDI monitors. The PC Board is quite simple. I have only one (1) PCB so comparing from one to another is impossible. They do not supply any scematics whatsoever. About the '' X '' I was mistaking, it's a '' V '' stamped on the part.   As for the '' accepted comment from me''  I registered on this board as requested, they sent me a confirmation email of which I replied and that allowed me to post a question SO that's why I assumed that I was accepted. If there is another way, i'd like to be informed please.   Sorry If I was misinterpreted.

Answer (score 5):

Probably a [2SK3065](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Rohm%20PDFs/2sk3065.pdf) 60V/2A n-channel MOSFET. SC-62 is another name for SOT-89.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That looks to be a SOT-89 package.  Most likely it is some kind of transistor or linear regulator.

This is a unlikely package for a diode.  I've seen diodes in SOT-23 packages, but by the time they need to dissipate more power they usually come in SMA packages.

Probe around with a ohmmeter, and maybe you can figure out what kind of transistor this is and which pins are what leads.

Comment: It could be a voltage regulator as well.

Comment: @Chu: Good point.  Added to the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this device is shorted on one side. Probing just showed up to be a transistorbetween left and center pin, the right one is shorted with the center one